# Core Data's inverse relation in detail

Tags: ios, core-data

I am having hard time wrapping my head around Core Data's inverse relationship. For example let's say there are two entities: `post` and `comment`, where

- `post` has_many `comments` and
- `comment` belongs_to `post`

Using xcode's visual coredata editor I would create both entities and then link them by:

1. Connecting `post` to destination `comment` and selecting `to many`
2. Connecting `comment` to destination `post` and not selecting `to many`
3. Make sure the relationship from #2 above is an `inverse` of #1.

#### Here's my question:

1. What is actually going on behind the scenes when you select `inverse`. What is this equivalent to in other `ORM`s, say ActiveRecord.
2. Will it have the same effect if instead of specifying #2's inverse as #1, I went to #1 and said its inverse is #2?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase I hear most often is that CoreData is about maintaining an object graph foremost, and an ORM second.  So with that in mind, I'd say that behind the scenes when you set an `inverse` relationship you are noting that it is a bi-directional relationship and not two, one way relationships.  Without that, you may be able to specify that a `comment` has many `posts` but if you add a post to a comment you may not be able to traverse the graph from the comment to the post and then back.

Coming from ActiveRecord that may not make much sense if you think about it as keeping keys in columns and noting the relationships - but CoreData can have many different data storage formats and an inverse relationship is not implied by storing the data.

It should have the same effect if you go to #1 and said its inverse is #2 - but that's easy to test and see.

Comment: How does `bi-directional relationship` function differently compared to `two unrelated one way relationships`? Do you mean without specifying `inverse` I can't do something like `[post.comments objectAtIndex: 0].post`? If so, I wonder why that is the case, because theoretically `[post.comments objectAtIndex: 0]` should return a comment object, and accessing a `post` from a comment should have no issue.

Comment: In your example, having an inverse assures that going from post to comment returns the right post.  The assumption your making is that if you can go from a post to a comment, you can go from a comment back to the same post which is what the inverse defines.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW6 has more

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting an inverse means that if you change one relationship then the inverse is kept in sync.  For example if you add a Comment to a Post then the Comment's "post" relationship will automatically be set.  Similarly if you do set a Comment's post property then that Comment will automatically be added to the Post's comments collection.  So the following two lines of code are equivalent:

   ```
   newComment.post = aPost;
   [aPost addCommentsObject:newComment];
   ```

If you did not specify the inverse then you would have to include BOTH lines to create the relationships.  Inverses are recommended because it is easier to maintain the integrity of the object graph.  How this is actually persisted in the store depends on the store type, but if you are using a sqlite store then it's easy to peek inside to see what Core Data is doing.

1. They are equivalent.